# my code keeps on giving me segfaults when I try to break it up into three smaller functions

Tags: c

I've tried passing the values by reference. the program reads a single line every time the function get_next_line is called and returns `1` if a line is found, `0` if a line is not found and `-1` for other errors such as failed memory allocation. the code leaks but for now my main problem is breaking up the get_next_line function.

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

char *ft_strnew(size_t size)
{
    char *str;

    str = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
    if (!str)
        return (NULL);
    str[strlen(str) + 1] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

void *ft_memset(void *start, int init, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *ptr;

    ptr = (unsigned char*)start;
    while (size > 0)
    {
        *ptr++ = (unsigned char)init;
        size--;
    }
    return (start);
}

void ft_bzero(void *s, size_t size)
{
    ft_memset(s, '\0', size);
}

char *ft_strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    char    *new;
    size_t  len;

    if (!s1 || !s2)
        return (NULL);
    len = strlen((char *)s1) + strlen((char *)s2);
    new = (char *)malloc(len + 1);
    if (!new)
        return (NULL);
    while (*s1 != '\0')
        *new++ = *s1++;
    while (*s2 != '\0')
        *new++ = *s2++;
    *new = '\0';
    return (new - len);
}

char *ft_strdup(const char *str)
{
    char    *strdup;
    int     i;

    strdup = (char *)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (strdup == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        strdup[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    strdup[i] = '\0';
    return (strdup);
}

static char *read_line(int f, int fd, char *buff, char *temp)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (f > 0)
    {
        if (buff[i] == '\n'){
            break;
        }
        else if (i == BUFF_SIZE)
        {
            f = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
            if (f == 0)
            {
                if (BUFF_SIZE == 1)
                    return (temp);      
                return ((char *)LINE_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            temp = ft_strjoin(temp, buff);
            i = -1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (temp);
}

int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    static t_var var;
    char buff[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
    char *new;
    int i;
    int f = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int w = 0;
    i = 0;

    if (fd <  0 || line == NULL)
        return (INVALID);
    ft_bzero(buff, BUFF_SIZE + 1);
    if (var.j > 0)
    {
        new = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (var.j + 1));
        if (!new)
            return (INVALID);
        s = strlen(var.temp) - var.j;
        f = s;
        w = var.j;
        while (var.temp[s] != '\0')
        {
            new[i] = var.temp[s];
            if (var.temp[s] == '\n')
            {
                if(!(*line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 1))))
                    return (INVALID);
                *line = strncpy(*line, new, i);
                var.j--;
                return (LINE_FOUND);
            }
            s++;
            var.j--;
            i++;
        }
        s = f;
        var.temp = ft_strdup(new);
    }//first read after this if statement
    if (w == 0)
        var.temp = ft_strnew(BUFF_SIZE);
    f = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
    if (f == 0)
        return (LINE_NOT_FOUND);
    var.temp = ft_strjoin(var.temp, buff);
    var.temp = read_line(f, fd, buff, var.temp);//function call 
    if (var.temp == (char *)LINE_NOT_FOUND)
        return (0);
    s = 0;
    if (var.temp[s])
    {
        while (var.temp[s] != '\n')
            s++;
    }
    s++;
    if(var.j == 0)
        *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (s + 1));
    *line = strncat(*line, var.temp, s - 1);
    var.j = strlen(var.temp) - s;
    return (LINE_FOUND);
}

#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     fd;
    char    *line;
    int     x = 1;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        while (x == 1)
        {
            x = get_next_line(fd, &line);
            if (x > 0)
                printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        close(fd);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: sorry if possible can you please point out redundant code or unnecessary code.  The read line function and the get_next_line functions are the main functions the other functions where just added from other files for clarity

Comment: `str[strlen(str) + 1] = '\0';` is wrong because `str` is not assigned any value, just memory is allocated for it. This means that `strlen` will go on to search for a NUL-terminator checking uninitialized memory locations invoking Undefined Behavior

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) E.g. `str = malloc(size + 1); if (!str) return (NULL); *str = 0; return (str);`

Comment: ohh thanks that makes lots of sense

Comment: You can't `strlen(str)` when `str` only contains garbage values. Where does `strlen` stop? (in other words `str` doesn't contain a valid string immediately after a call to `malloc`) You can use `calloc` to zero all bytes in the new memory, but that renders `strlen(str)` unnecessary.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960927/how-can-i-break-up-the-get-next-line-functon-and-also-can-you-help-remove-redund.

Answer (score 4):

In both `str[strlen(str) + 1] = '\0';` and `s = strlen(var.temp) - var.j;`, you call `strlen` on things that are *not* strings. Only a valid string may be passed to `strlen`. Look at this code:

```
str = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
if (!str)
    return (NULL);
str[strlen(str) + 1] = '\0';
```

You pass `str` to `strlen` even though you just allocated it and it points to a buffer that contains random garbage. You cannot do that. The interface contract for `strlen` says that you must pass it a pointer to memory that contains a string. Random garbage may or may not be a valid string.

The same is true of `var.temp` when you pass it to `strlen`. It doesn't contain a valid string because you haven't placed a valid string in it yet.

Comment: `str[strlen(str) + 1] = '\0';` : I was convinced that a series of characters ending with a NULL was actually a string in C!! And that is exactly what the OP is doing - making sure that the parsing will finish at the right character. Will you please explain why your argument is valid? Why is it wrong to count the amount of garbage, as long as it does the job and does nothing bad - out of boundary stuff, over / under-flows... It is definitely inefficient, but efficiency is not the topic of the question. For the second statement, `var` is not initialized before `strlen()`, so the answer stands.

Comment: @virolino This series of characters does not end with NUL, so it is not a string, so you can't pass it to `strlen`, which expects a string.

Comment: @virolino Let's put it this way: given `char *str = malloc(size + 1); if (!str) return NULL;`, what would be the *expected* result of `strlen(str)`? Is there any? Why don't  just use `str[size] = '\0';` or `calloc`?

Comment: Wow! I was so impressed that OP cared to add a NULL that I did not notice the horror of the `strlen()`. Sorry for my "slip", entire answer is actually correct. `str[size]` would be the correct way to do it, agree. +1